# Undefined constructer in code employing the use of PDFbox repository

Tags: java, maven, pdfbox

This is my first time using a Maven repository so apologies if its a simple resolution.

My  code is as follows:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessRead;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

public class application {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
    PDDocument pdDoc = null;
    COSDocument cosDoc = null;
    File file = new File("/Users/Desktop/Corporate reports/previous 'fetch' items/ARM2009.pdf");
    try {
        PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
        parser.parse();
        cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
        pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
        pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
        pdfStripper.setEndPage(5);
        String parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
        System.out.println(parsedText);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Failed to parse : " +file);
    } 
}

}
```

Essentially, the  19th line where it say:

```
PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
```

is giving an error at compile time. It is saying:

The constructor PDFParser(FileInputStream) is 
 undefined

I am not sure how to handle this. My IDE recommends cast the argument to RandomAccessRead but this just ends up with a different error at run time

Please help thank you.

Comment: where does maven come in here? it's not clear

Comment: Instead of the 5 lines after the "try", just do this `pdDoc = PDDocument.load(file)` and then construct your textStripper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compare javadocs for the pdfparser in pdfbox [v2](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfparser/PDFParser.html) vs [v1.8](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.10/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfparser/PDFParser.html), you will notice that the constructor definition has changed from

```
PDFParser(InputStream input)
```

to

```
PDFParser(RandomAccessRead source)
```

So please make sure you reference the correct version from maven. If you plan to stick to version 2, make sure to use something like [RandomAccessFile](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/io/RandomAccessFile.html), not a FileInputStream.